# Visual Studio 2017: shortcut to create new SQL query

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Having trouble finding the right command in Tools\Options\Environment\Keyboard to set a shortcut for creating a new query when focus is in SQL Server Explorer.

I'll continue with my try-n-error....but perhaps someone already tracked it down?

[image]

Comment: If you have one query already open, you can create new ones with Ctrl-Alt-N, but I don't see a way to open the first one via shortcut.

Comment: That might be :-( But there are at least two menu-commands for this: The context-menu and the the tool menu `Tools\SQL Server\New Query`
I would be surprised if one of those menus was not accessible in the keyboard shortcut assign windows (somewhere)

Comment: Just noticed the **Quick Launch** in the upper-right corner (**Ctrl+Q**). I can search for  e.g. `query`...it will take my to it without touching the mouse, but still not as quick as a direct shortcut